# What repositories are you using for 10.10 software?

Tags: 10.10, repository, software-sources

Here is hoping that this is not duplicated somewhere else...

Back before the easy addition of Launchpad PPAs, many of us used to customize our sources list to include user/3rd party repositories. Some ambitious Ubuntu'ers would even maintain updated lists on their websites.  It was the easiest way to install software for things like Google Earth in the earlier days.

So the question I am asking may prove useful for the newcomers and for the experienced.

What other repositories (like Medibuntu) have you found useful for 10.10 (other than PPAs)?

Answer (score 2):

The getdeb repositories (and playdeb ones) for sure : go there to see more, it's better to see it yourself !  : http://www.getdeb.net/welcome/

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that there is a general movement towards PPA's of individual devs. As winniemie point out, there is getdeb.net, but there is also ubuntu-tweak.com that serves out individual packages, both via the site and then their application, ubuntutweak.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox is the only non-Canonical or non-PPA repository I use right now.

Oh actually... It's still a PPA but it's more than one application. In 10.04 I used a "rolling updates" PPA. It was basically an aggregation of several other PPAs. It wasn't a daily pull but rather more stable updates. I use the  Maverick version now though they're still getting up to speed, adding new things.

[Maverick quasi rolling :)](https://launchpad.net/~guido-iodice/+archive/guiodicmaverick)